# calling two async functions one after another in .post function Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I want to receive an image from a client, convert it into text and then delete the image once it's converted. I'm using the following code:

```
app.post('/upload', (req,res)=>{
    const myFile = req.files.file;
    myFile.mv(`D:/web_projects/react-express-mongodb-template/server/pictures/${myFile.name}`)
    
    let img = `D:/web_projects/react-express-mongodb-template/server/pictures/${myFile.name}`
    convert(img);
    remove(img)
    
})
app.listen(5000, () => {
    console.log('server is running at port 5000');
})
async function convert(img){
  const worker = createWorker();
    
  console.log(worker)
  await worker.load();
  await worker.loadLanguage('eng');
  await worker.initialize('eng');
  const { data: { text } } = await worker.recognize(img);
  console.log(text);
  await worker.terminate();
    
}
async function remove(path){
  try {
    fs.unlink(path)
  } catch(err) {
    console.error(err)
  }
}
```

So in the post method I call the convert function and then remove but remove gets executed first and so convert function results in error. Is there a way to handle this issue?

Comment: What is `createWorker`?

Comment: it's needed to convert images to text

Comment: Yes, but what is its definition? Are you sure those `worker` methods return promises?

Comment: Tbh I don't know the definition but I'm sure it returns promises as I found this code on official github page of tesseract.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `convert` is an `async` function, and thus returns a promise, replace:

```
convert(img);
remove(img)
```

With:

```
convert(img).then(() => remove(img));
```

However, this assumes that all awaited `worker` method calls in `convert` return promises. If this is not the case, and they run asynchronous code, then actually `convert` will not properly await those, and you should first promisify them.